# How to enforce strict serialization of JSON in Play 2.x

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

Play's JSON serialization is by default permissive when serializing from JSON into a case class.  For example.

```
case class Stuff(name: String, value: Option[Boolean])

implicit val stuffReads: Reads[Stuff] = (
  ( __ \ 'name).read[String] and
  ( __ \ 'value).readNullable[Boolean]
)(Stuff.apply _)
```

If the following JSON was received:

```
{name: "My Stuff", value: true, extraField: "this shouldn't be here"}
```

It will succeed with a 'JsSuccess' and discard the 'extraField'.

Is there a way to construct the Json Reads function to have it return a JsError if there are 'unhandled' fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can verify that the object doesn't contain extra keys before performing your own decoding:

```
import play.api.data.validation.ValidationError

def onlyFields(allowed: String*): Reads[JsObject] = Reads.filter(
  ValidationError("One or more extra fields!")
)(_.keys.forall(allowed.contains))
```

Or if you don't care about error messages (and that one's not very helpful, anyway):

```
def onlyFields(allowed: String*): Reads[JsObject] =
  Reads.verifying(_.keys.forall(allowed.contains))
```

And then:

```
implicit val stuffReads: Reads[Stuff] = onlyFields("name", "value") andThen (
  (__ \ 'name).read[String] and
  (__ \ 'value).readNullable[Boolean]
)(Stuff)
```

The repetition isn't very nice, but it works.

Comment: wondering if you would do this differently today to add more compile time magic to get `case class` property names vs `onlyFields("name", "value")` variadic function? hard coding property names in`onlyFields` approach works but running into maintenance challenge to remember updating/adding/removing  field names in `onlyFields` when `case class` is modified because `onlyFields` has no compile time safety it doesn't reveal missing properties until unit tests/runtime. is there a way to even achieve this at compile time?

Comment: You could definitely do this with a macro, or more cleanly with Shapeless's `LabelledGeneric`. I'll try to find some time to write up a blog post that'll do this `LabelledGeneric`, but I can't promise I'll get to it this week.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired from [Travis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334519/travis-brown)' comment to use `LabelledGeneric` I was able achieve compile time safe solution.

```
object toStringName extends Poly1 {
    implicit def keyToStrName[A] = at[Symbol with A](_.name)
}
case class Foo(bar: String, boo: Boolean)

val labl = LabelledGeneric[Foo]
val keys = Keys[labl.Repr].apply
```

now `keys.map (toStringName).toList` will give you

`res0: List[String] = List(bar, boo)`