# PlayFramework in Scala, Reads - error in case of unknown key?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have a custom `Reads` for my object:

```
implicit val myReads: Reads[MyObject] = (
    (__ \ "id").readNullable[UUID] and
    (__ \ "name").readNullable[String]
)(MyObject.apply _)
```

Can I have it fail if an unknown key is provided? For instance, I would like it to fail when trying to parse such Json,

```
{ "key" : 1234 }
```

so that `request.body.validate[MyObject]` would result in a `JsError`. Thanks!

Comment: may be this can be of some help => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297985/how-to-enforce-strict-serialization-of-json-in-play-2-x

Comment: thanks mane! it looks my question is a duplicate :)